# How to update XRReferenceObjectLibrary from remote in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm a newbie in Unity, c# and apple system, but I need to find a solution to this problem. I'm building an app for Ipad pro to recognise some object. I've generated the .arobject file of the scanned objects, imported in an XRReferenceObjectLibrary and everything works fine BUT I need to update the library from remote (assetbundle or addressable or another process). I'm totally in the dark. Please save me!

Comment: What do you need to update and why you need to update?

Comment: I need to add a XRReferenceObject (with an .arobject) in the XRReferenceObjectLibrary because this app is like a "client" of models and need update of this library 2 or 3 times every month. So my intent is to update/add object to this library via remote database (assetbundle or addressable but these doesn't seems to work for the .arobject)